# Display on Excel conga merge

Tags: excel, conga

is there  way to display on conga excel merge only sub total of items, then the grand total?
i.e.
Gross Revenue
370

### 1200

total 1570
the use does not need to see the 370 and the 1200. the use only need to see the summary 1570

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest method would be to use an Aggregated SOQL Query in lieu of a Salesforce report to pull the data from Salesforce.  The merge data would already be summarized.  Another option... you could merge the raw data to a hidden sheet in the workbook, then use native Excel formulas to aggregate and display the summarized data elsewhere.